# FFT does not give harmonics not integer multiple of fundamental frequency

Tags: audio, fft

FFT does not give harmonics not integer multiple of fundamental frequency.

this is result of FFT (fundamental frequency is 441.4307 Hz(index:328))
where index is location of x of a FFT graph

[image]

```
2 harmonic freq = 884.2072(index:657)
3 harmonic freq = 1328.3295(index:987)
4 harmonic freq = 1775.1434(index:1319)
5 harmonic freq = 2221.9574(index:1651)
6 harmonic freq = 2675.5005(index:1988)
7 harmonic freq = 3135.7727(index:2330)
8 harmonic freq = 3592.0074(index:2669)
9 harmonic freq = 4064.3921(index:3020)
10 harmonic freq = 4531.3934(index:3367)
11 harmonic freq = 5011.8530(index:3724)
12 harmonic freq = 5480.2002(index:4072)
13 harmonic freq = 5943.1641(index:4416)
14 harmonic freq = 6420.9320(index:4771)
15 harmonic freq = 6887.9333(index:5118)
16 harmonic freq = 7346.8597(index:5459)
17 harmonic freq = 7805.7861(index:5800)
18 harmonic freq = 8264.7125(index:6141)
19 harmonic freq = 8723.6389(index:6482)
20 harmonic freq = 9167.7612(index:6812)
```

as you seen, its not perfectly integer multiple of fundamental frequency.

its error is getting bigger.

when I mix two sounds(notes), i cannot find harmonics of one sound.

How can I find harmonics more accurately?

**EDIT:**

the graph is from this code

actually i did stft, and each frame size is 2^15(32768)

```
s = np.fft.rfft(frames)
```

so there are several frames(0, 1, 2, ... ,n)
And i got frequency from this code

```
timebins, freqbins = np.shape(s)
allfreqs = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(2^15, 1./44100)[:freqbins+1])
```

from this code i got allgreqs[0] = 1.3

And the graph above is one of s(s[i])

I wonder why those bins are not integer multiple

first selected bin(red) is 441 Hz where x = 328
and 20th selected bin(last yellow) is 9167 Hz where x = 6812

I found several webs that say that every harmonics are integer multiple of fundamental frequency(1st harmonic = fundamental frequency, 2nd harmonic = (fundamental frequency * 2) and so on...)

I expected 20th selected bin to be 8820 Hz and x = 6560 as 20 times of fundamental frequency.

the error is getting bigger as calculating more harmonic frequencies.

why does this happen? how can i fix this.

Comment: Think of each FFT output as a "bin" rather than a point. The frequency of a bin is just its *centre frequency*. The *width* of each bin is `Fs/N`.

Comment: when I calculated each point, its interval was 1.3 Hz. So... I thought that red dot, 328th index, was 441 Hz. Is my calculation wrong?

Comment: See comment above: think of each FFT output as a bin with a centre frequency and a finite width, not a point. Your question is not very clear though - maybe [edit] it to add a bit more context, and your code ?

Comment: edited... i wonder why harmonics are not integer multiples of fundamental frequency